# How to have a Multi Character Delimiter in Informatica Cloud?

Tags: etl, delimiter, informatica, flat-file, informatica-cloud

I have a problem I need help solving. The business I am working for is using Informatica cloud to do alot of their ETL into AWS and Other Services.

We have been given a flat file by the business where the field delimiter is "~|" Currently to the best of my knowledge informatica only accepts a single character delimiter.

[image: Only a Single Character. How do I make it Multiple?]

Does any one know how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

Informatica cannot read [composite delimiters](https://network.informatica.com/thread/26271).

> First you could feed each line as one single long string into an
>   Expression transformation. In this case the delimiter character should
>   be set to \037 , I haven't seen this character (ASCII Unit Separator)
>   in use at least since 1982. Then use repetitive invocations of InStr()
>   within the EXP to identify the positions of those double pipe
>   characters and split up each line into fields using SubStr().
>
> Second
>   (easier in the mapping, more work with the session) you could feed the
>   file into some utility which replaces those double pipe characters by
>   the character ASCII 31 (the Unit Separator mentioned above); the
>   session has to be set up such that it reads the output from this
>   utility (input file type = Command instead of File). Then the source
>   definition should contain the \037 as the field delimiter instead of
>   any pipe character or so.